Move multiple folder structure along files from one blob container to another in different storage accounts using Logic app
I have Blob container contains multiple folders ,sub folder and files. I have to create a logic app to copy folders ,sub folder and files to another container in different storage account.
I used below flow but ended with some errors
For Example i have storage account - strtest1
Container name - Test
Contains folder - RPA and it contains multiple subfolders and files.
I have to copy RPA folder along with multiple subfolders and files to different container test2 in different storage account strtest2.
Please find below workflow which i used.


What errors did you get?

Specified blob doesnot exist


Move multiple folder structure along files from one blob container to another in different storage accounts using Logic app

You can use below design which worked for me:

then:

then:

Output:


Hi @RithwikBojja What "flat listing" does from list blob action. For me it was set to "no" so i was getting issues. Now after setting it to Yes it worked.

Glad it worked out @HemantKumar
